# How to add text shadow to overlay text using PHP

Tags: php, php-gd

I want to add an overlay text with text shadow to an image. So far I have been able to achieve this
`// top text
        imagettftext($im, $font_size+2, 0,
            $text1_params['centered_start'],
            $font_size+$margin,
            $black, $font, $text1_params['text']
        );
        imagettftext($im, $font_size, 0,
            $text1_params['centered_start'],
            $font_size+$margin,
            $white, $font, $text1_params['text']
        );
// bottom text
        imagettftext($im, $font_size, 0,
            $text2_params['centered_start'] ,
            $image_height-$text2_params['height']+$font_size+$margin,
            $black, $font, $text2_params['text']
        );
        imagettftext($im, $font_size, 0,
            $text2_params['centered_start']-2,
            $image_height-$text2_params['height']+$font_size+$margin-2,
            $white, $font, $text2_params['text']
        );`

This is what the result looks like-

[image]
But I want it to look like this(Notice the subtle difference in both the text shadows)-

[image]

Comment: which of the images is the "want this" version? shadows to the bottom/right of the text, or shadows all around the word (e.g. not a shadow, just a thick border)

Comment: @MarcB- I want to achieve the bottom one. Sorry about the confusion. There were some formatting mistakes

Comment: The bottom one is called stroked text, not shadowed text ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hackish way is to render the black text 8 times.  First time with an offset to the top left, then top center, then top right, then left, and so on.  It may leave an outline that's missing some pixels in a few places but it likely won't be noticeable.